# comment out in SublimeText for SASS files not working corectly / instead of //

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

I have this problem in SublimeText 3: when commenting out text it is commented with '/' instead of '//' what of course causes compile errors.

How to fix?

I am using:

```
Sass 3.3.4 (Maptastic Maple)
```

on Mac OS X

I comment it out like normally everything in Sublime Text on  Mac OS X that is

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: How do you comment it out? It works alright for me using `Super+Shift+/`. I'm using the [Sass package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sass) by nathos.

Comment: It would really help us to know what packages you have installed.

Comment: @idleberg I also updated info about the way on which I comment it out.

Comment: @andi - In Sublime, what syntax is shown for your Sass files, and also which packages are installed in Sublime?

Comment: @KatieK what do you mean by saying `what syntax is shown for your Sass files`?

Comment: @From View > Syntax, which is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a bit asahmed by the fact, that it was just about this:

[image]

By default SublimeText was treating (guessing) that the code is of Ruby Haml file.